# Expected Value Question with Money

Tags: probability

I've been struggling a lot w/ expected value, and was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

I know the equation for expected value is $E(X)$ $=$ $NP$

The question asks:

> A 20 dollar bill, two 10 dollar bills, three 5 dollar bills and four 1 dollar bills are placed in a bag. If a bill is chosen at random, what is the expected value for the amount chosen?

I believe the equation would go something like

$E(X) = 20(p) + 10(p) + 5(p) + 1(p)$ but I'm not sure what I would add for P? Theres a total of 10 bills that can be chosen, so would the probability be something like

$E(X) = 20(1/10) + 10(2/10) + 5(3/10) + 1(4/10)$

Comment: Your last line is the appropriate weighted average!

Answer (score 1):

> I know the equation for expected value is $E(X) = NP $

That is so for a *binomial distribution*.   However, this is *not* that.   So it is just the wrong equation for this situation.

> I believe the equation would go something like
>   $$E(X) ~=~ 20(1/10) + 10(2/10) + 5(3/10) + 1(4/10)$$

*Now* you are on the right track.   In this instance, *that* is the correct calculation of the *mean*, in .   (Also known as the weighted average; or the expectation.)

---

Don't doubt yourself.   It appears that you were just trying to apply the wrong shortcut, and that was confusing you, *because* otherwise you do know what you are about.   You have got the basics down.

$\Box$

Comment: What is the correct equation for these sort of questions? Just so I know which ones to apply to what question =)

Comment: $\Sigma( p_i\cdot x_i)$